# How to stop Jackson ObjectMapper from mapping the string "null" to null when mapping ByteArray -> Object Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jackson

Hi I am using Kotlin JacksonObject mapper to map and having some issues,

I start with a JSON string that looks like this

```
{
  "name": "testName",
  "age": "null",
}
```

And an object that looks like this

```
{
val name: String,
val age: Int?
}
```

I want to deserialise the JSON string into the object and for it to throw an error when it tries to map the string "null" to the age which is expected to be an int or null. Right now the JacksonMapper is converting this "null" string into the value Null and giving me the object below

```
{
"name" = "testName",
"age" = null
}
```

Is there an easy way to configure the behaviour of this mapper so that it uses strict typing and doesn't automatically map the strings into what it presumes they are?

Comment: Don't spam with irrelevant tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS`. If set to `false`, it will prevent `ObjectMapper` from coercing String representations of numbers and booleans into their Java counterparts. Only strict conversions will be allowed.

See below an example of its usage

```
package com.stackoverflow

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.registerKotlinModule
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNull
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.assertThrows

data class JSON(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int?
)

class ObjectMapperTest {

    private val objectMapper =
        ObjectMapper()
            .registerKotlinModule()
            .configure(MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS, false)

    @Test
    fun mapStringTest() {
        assertThrows<MismatchedInputException> {
            objectMapper.readValue(
                """
            {
              "name": "testName",
              "age": "null"
            }
            """.trimIndent(),
                JSON::class.java
            )
        }

        assertThrows<MismatchedInputException> {
            objectMapper.readValue(
                """
            {
              "name": "testName",
              "age": "1"
            }
            """.trimIndent(),
                JSON::class.java
            )
        }

        assertEquals(1,  objectMapper.readValue(
            """
            {
              "name": "testName",
              "age": 1
            }
            """.trimIndent(),
            JSON::class.java
        ).age)

        assertNull(objectMapper.readValue(
            """
            {
              "name": "testName"
            }
            """.trimIndent(),
            JSON::class.java
        ).age)
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is about how to force the mapper to throw an error if the entry for 'age' is not an integer in the JSON data.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the issue, see my modification to the answer which might be what you need